# Oracle - Not a single-group group function

Tags: sql, oracle, count, group-by, max

For the following sql command

```
select h.hacker_id
    ,h.name
    ,challenges_created
from hackers h
inner join (
    select hacker_id
        ,count(*) as challenges_created /* line 1 */
    from challenges
    group by hacker_id
    order by 2 desc
    ) tmp on h.hacker_id = tmp.hacker_id
order by challenges_created desc
    ,h.hacker_id;
```

**so far so good but**

As soon as I try to add `max(count(*)) as maximum` to the line 1 it give error as:

> Not a single-group group function

This is the code for which it gives error :

```
select h.hacker_id
    ,h.name
    ,challenges_created
from hackers h
inner join (
    select hacker_id
        ,count(*) as challenges_created
        ,max(count(*)) as maximum
    from challenges
    group by hacker_id
    ) tmp on h.hacker_id = tmp.hacker_id
order by challenges_created desc
    ,h.hacker_id;
```

I am basically interested in getting the maximum count i.e. maximum number of `challenges created` so far.

I am new to sql, kindly help and oblige. Thanks in advance. And yes, of course! I know many such question have been asked in recent past but none matches my situation which is why I am asking it again.

Comment: Please add table structure, 5-6 records as sample data and output you expect in your question.

Comment: When I tried this in SQL Server, I get an error `Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.` So I'm thinking this is something similar to what you are seeing. I think you'll have to add another `Join` to get the `Max(Count(*))`.

Comment: @WEI_DBA : Is it not possible to achieve it in this query itself ? What if i can use something like `top` which we can in sql ? Is there anything similar to `top` in oracle too?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with x as (
  select h.hacker_id, h.name, count(*) challenges_created 
  from hackers h 
  inner join challenges on h.hacker_id = challenges.hacker_id
  group by h.hacker_id, h.name
)
select x.*, 
       (select max(challenges_created) from x) as "max"
from x
order by challenges_created desc, hacker_id;
```